# unable to set value to a bound property

Tags: vue.js

I would like to know why i am getting the following error:

```
 error  'msg_' is assigned a value but never used
```

despite that the variable `msg_` is used in the following context as shown in the below posted code:

```
<HelloWorld :msg="msg_"/>
```

**App.vue**:

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  <HelloWorld :msg="msg_"/>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  setup(props) {
    
    var msg_ = ref({msg:"msg from parent"})
  
    return {
      props
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return **msg_** from the **setup()** function.

```
setup(props) {
  var msg_ = ref({msg:"msg from parent"})
  
  return {
    props,
    msg_,
  }
}
```

Also it better to use const and let instead of var.